# first loop through everything, than if 1 is true do something

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I have this foreach loop that checks if `$testsubject` is equal to the results from the array.

But I want it to check all the results first and if one is true than go further and check the date and else just echo that the voucher is not corect.

the purpose of the code is that the user puts in a voucher code which for now is `$testsubject` than I check if the voucher exists in the system if that is true I check if it is not expired with the date function and then I cut the discount for the price `$testamount`.

image of the echo's https://imagebin.ca/v/3xQuiAClVsAG

*index.php*

```
function display()
{
    $arrContextOptions = [
        "ssl" => [
            "verify_peer"      => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
        ],
    ];
    $getVoucherList   = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=yourkey&resource_id=110556";
    $cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
    $voucherlist      = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    $voucherList      = json_decode($voucherlist, true);
    $testsubject      = "TESTVOUCHER";
    $testamount       = "5,00";
    foreach ($voucherList['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr) {
        if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
            echo $testsubject . " is not equal to " . $testVoucherArr['code'] . "<br>";
            echo $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date'] . "<br>";
            echo $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br>";
            if (date("Y-m-d") <= $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date']) {
                echo "this code can be used <br>";
                echo $testamount - $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br>";
            } else {
                echo "this code cannot be used";
            }
            ;
        } else {
            echo $testsubject . " is not equal to " .
                $testVoucherArr['code'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    display();
}
```

Comment: Why do you not explain anywhere what the purpose of your code is, and what it all means? Not in your question, and not in your code.

Comment: Set a variable to `false`, loop through your items, if any item matches your condition set said variable to `true` and stop your loop. Then check for that variable

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you? If the code is valid, then you enter a function which checks the date. After the function has ended, the foreach loop will end by using "break;"

```
function testVoucherDate($voucher)
{
    if (date("Y-m-d") <= $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date']) {
        echo "this code can be used <br>";
        echo $testamount - $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "this code cannot be used";
    };
}

foreach ($voucherList['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr) {
    if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
        echo $testsubject . " is not equal to " . $testVoucherArr['code'] . "<br>";
        echo $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date'] . "<br>";
        echo $testVoucherArr['discount_value'] . "<br>";
        testVoucherDate($testVoucherArr);
        break;
    } else {
        echo $testsubject . " is not equal to " .
            $testVoucherArr['code'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've put the function above the loop, so no errors of undefined functions will occur

Comment: i get this error when I tried it: Fatal error: Call to undefined function testVoucherDate()

Comment: I fixed it, just moved the function above the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

First set a flag to `true`, then loop setting the flag to `false` if there is an error. Then test the flag:

```
$flag = true;                          // SET A FLAG
foreach($a as $b){
    if($b !== 'Hello')$flag = false;   // IF contidtion not met, set flag to true
    }
if($flag === false){                   // TEST IF flag result
    echo 'Dear oh dear';die;
    }
foreach(....){                         // GO ON if flag === true
    ....
    }
```

Comment: I get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Ah sorry, must be `as` in the `foreach`

Comment: now I get this warning Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()